Missing comma in Harvard citations with journal class
This problem is with using the Sage LaTeX Template. Based on their Harvard style guide, "If author’s name is not in the text, insert last name, comma and year". This appears to be correctly encoded in the shown excerpt from the cls file. However, for the mwe, the comma is missing from the displayed in-text citation.
sagej.cls
\if@sageh
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{}{}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{16pt}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\refsize}
\renewcommand\refname{{\normalsize References}}
\fi

mwe.tex
\documentclass[
sageh
% ,sagev
% ,sageapa
]{sagej}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith2024,
  author = {John Smith},
  title = {An Example Article},
  journal = {Journal of Examples},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {42},
  number = {7},  pages = {123--456},
  doi = {10.1234/example.2024.42.7.123}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item It has been argued \citep{smith2024}: \dots
\item It has been argued by \cite{smith2024}: \dots
\end{itemize}

\makeatletter
BibStyle:~
\if@sageh
  Harvard
\bibliographystyle{SageH}
\fi
\if@sagev
  Vancouver
\bibliographystyle{SageV}
\fi
\if@sageapa
  APA
  \bibliographystyle{SageH}
\fi
\makeatother
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

Terminal:
$ find . -type f -name 'mwe.*' | grep -v 'tex' | while read path; do rm "${path}"; done
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
$ bibtex mwe
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
$ for i in {1..2}; do pdflatex mwe.tex; done

Also see:

Unable to display ... using SageJ
natbib's manual (added after answer posted)



@Mico I think OP means that the References section is "not in the text", and there the comma is missing.

@Marijn - Thanks for clearing up my confusion. I'll post an answer.

You appear to have identified a bug. To fix it, I suggest you add the instruction
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}

to the preamble.


\documentclass[sageh]{sagej}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith2024,
  author  = {John Smith},
  title   = {An Example Article},
  journal = {Journal of Examples},
  year    = {2024},
  volume  = {42},
  number  = {7},  
  pages   = {123--456},
  doi     = {10.1234/example.2024.42.7.123}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliographystyle{SageH} % employ 'natbib' citation management package
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}  % specify comma as the author-year separator

\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\citep{smith2024} \qquad \citet{smith2024}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}


A bug with natbib, you mean?

@Erwann - No, a bug in the way the document class implements its own formatting instructions. (The \bibpunct directive is the problem.)

@Erwann - The document class contains the instruction \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{}{}{,}; it's buggy because it should be \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{}{,}{,} -- note the comma in the 5th argument. To fix the bug, I find it easiest (and definitely more undertandable than \bibpunct syntax) to run \setcitestyle{aysep={,}}.
